# Uniqueness of minimal resolution

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a domain, and $a_1,\dots,a_r$ be a regular sequence of $R$. Let $b_1,\dots,b_r$ be another regular sequence, such that two regular sequences generate the same ideal, i.e. $(a_1,\dots,a_r)=(b_1,\dots,b_r)$. Is there any isomorphism $f:R^r \to R^r$ such that  $f(a_1,\dots,a_r)=(b_1,\dots,b_r)$?

This problem come from algebraic geometry where $Y$ is a subvariety of $X$ defined by a regular section $a$ of locally free sheaf $\mathcal{E}$. Then one has a minimal resolution where the differential is by contracting $a$:
$$ \wedge^*\mathcal{E}^* \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_Y \to 0$$

If there is another regular section $b \in \text{Hom}(X,\mathcal{E})$ which also gives $Y$, then we have another minimal resolution $$\wedge^*\mathcal{E}^* \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_Y \to 0$$ by contracting $b$.

I want to say these two resolutions are isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo, and I have edited already. First, I think one can say minimal resolution when the ring is not local, this should be understand when one $\otimes R_p$ for the complex, where $p \subset R$ is any prime ideal, the image of each differential lives in $p_p R^n$(suppose $R^n$ is some module in this complex). Besides, I don't understand what you said "...But this is true for any finitely generated module over a local ring". Want I really wan to show is there exists such isomorphism between $R^r \to R^r$ such that sending regular sequence to regular sequence.

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear, actually what you wrote as the first question is what I asked. The geometry part I wrote after that question is the explanation for where this question came from, and in my mind, this is equivalent to the algebraic question I asked. I gave the title of this question as" uniqueness of minimal resolution" which is a little misleading, but I cannot come up with better title cover the question I want to ask. Besides, could you elaborate on " on the local case two resolution are the same"?

Comment: You can view your resolutions as  quasi-isomorphisms $K_{a}^{\bullet} = [ \ \Lambda^* \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{O}_X] \to \mathcal{O}_Y$ and similarly for $K_{b}^{\bullet}$. That would mean that in the derived category all three are isomorphic: $\mathcal{O}_Y \cong K_a^{\bullet} \cong K_{b}^{\bullet}$, so both resolutions provide good models (locally free ones) for $\mathcal{O}_Y$. I don't see what more one can say